# How can I go about customizing the serialization with ServiceStack Redis impl

Tags: redis, servicestack

What is the easiest way to go about providing custom serialization for the ServiceStack redis library, https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

I have done some digging on google but with not too much luck except having to implement IRedisNativeClient... which sounds like a lot of work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a silly question really. The untyped client accepts a string parameter. And on further reading it seems that all the typed client does is serialize to a byte array and then encodes the bytes to a UTF8 string. So by using the un-typed client you can serialize however you like.